# Convert dataclass of dataclass to json string

Tags: python, json, class, oop, python-dataclasses

I have a json string that I want to read, convert it to an object that I can manipulate, and then convert it back into a json string.

I am utilizing the python 3.10 dataclass, and one of the attributes of the class is another class (**mySubClass**).  When I call  `json.loads(myClass)`, I get the following error: `TypeError: Object of type mySubClass is not JSON serializable.`

Is there a way I can instantiate the dataclass **myClass** with everything it needs (including **mySubClass**), and then have a "post init operation" that will convert **myClass.mySubClass** into a simple json str? Or am I going about this the wrong way?

My original goal was to have the following:

```
import json
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
mySubClass:
  sub_item1: str
  sub_item2: str

@dataclass
myClass:
  item1: str
  item2: mySubClass()

...
convert_new_jsonStr_toObj = json.loads(received_json_str, object_hook=lambda d: SimpleNamespace(**d))

...
#: Get new values/do "stuff" to the received json string

myClass_to_jsonStr = json.dumps(myClass(item1=convert_new_jsonStr_toObj.item1, item2=mySubClass(sub_item1=convert_new_jsonStr_toObj.sub_item1, sub_item2=convert_new_jsonStr_toObj.sub_item2)))

...
#: Final json will look something like:

processed_json_str = "{
   "item1" : "new_item1",
   "item2" : {
         "sub_item1": "new_sub_item1",
         "sub_item2": "new_sub_item2"
    }"
}
#: send processed_json_str back out...

#: Note: "processed_json_str" has the same structure as "received_json_str".
```

Comment: Does that represent your actual code? Because that's not valid Python.

Comment: This is not the actual code - this is just an example to try and portray the concept of my issue.  My "dataclass" has many many more "items" within it. Is there something wrong that would throw off the point(s) I am trying to convey?

Comment: When something is not working and the posted code has obvious errors (like, those aren't even valid Python class definitions), it can be hard to separate "not working due to syntax errors" vs "not working for more in depth reasons". Generally, it's always best for your question to include an [mcve]: something someone can copy and paste and locally reproduce the behavior you're asking about. I've taken a shot at an answer below; curoius if it helps out.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I've understood your question correctly, you can do something like this::

```
import json
import dataclasses

@dataclasses.dataclass
class mySubClass:
  sub_item1: str
  sub_item2: str

@dataclasses.dataclass
class myClass:
  item1: str
  item2: mySubClass

  # We need a __post_init__ method here because otherwise
  # item2 will contain a python dictionary, rather than
  # an instance of mySubClass.
  def __post_init__(self):
      self.item2 = mySubClass(**self.item2)


sampleData = '''
{
  "item1": "This is a test",
  "item2": {
    "sub_item1": "foo",
    "sub_item2": "bar"
  }
}
'''

myvar = myClass(**json.loads(sampleData))
myvar.item2.sub_item1 = 'modified'
print(json.dumps(dataclasses.asdict(myvar)))
```

Running this produces:

```
{"item1": "This is a test", "item2": {"sub_item1": "modified", "sub_item2": "bar"}}
```

---

As a side note, this all becomes easier if you use a more fully featured package like [pydantic](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/):

```
import json
from pydantic import BaseModel

class mySubClass(BaseModel):
  sub_item1: str
  sub_item2: str

class myClass(BaseModel):
  item1: str
  item2: mySubClass

sampleData = '''
{
  "item1": "This is a test",
  "item2": {
    "sub_item1": "foo",
    "sub_item2": "bar"
  }
}
'''

myvar = myClass(**json.loads(sampleData))
myvar.item2.sub_item1 = 'modified'
print(myvar.json())
```

Answer (score 3):

Without using any libraries other than the builtins:

```py
import dataclasses
import json


@dataclasses.dataclass
class mySubClass:
    sub_item1: str
    sub_item2: str


@dataclasses.dataclass
class myClass:
    item1: str
    item2: mySubClass

    @classmethod
    def from_json(cls, string: str):
        data: dict = json.loads(string)
        if isinstance(data['item2'], dict):
            data['item2'] = mySubClass(**data['item2'])
        return cls(**data)

    def json(self):
        return json.dumps(self, default=lambda o: o.__dict__)


sampleData = '''
{
  "item1": "This is a test",
  "item2": {
    "sub_item1": "foo",
    "sub_item2": "bar"
  }
}
'''

myvar = myClass.from_json(sampleData)
myvar.item2.sub_item1 = 'modified'
print(myvar.json())
```

Which becomes a bit easier, using a ser/de library like [`dataclass-wizard`](https://dataclass-wizard.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), or `dataclasses-json`:

```py
import dataclasses

from dataclass_wizard import JSONWizard


@dataclasses.dataclass
class myClass(JSONWizard):
    item1: str
    item2: 'mySubClass'

    # optional
    @property
    def json(self, indent=None):
        return self.to_json(indent=indent)


@dataclasses.dataclass
class mySubClass:
    sub_item1: str
    sub_item2: str


sampleData = '''
{
  "item1": "This is a test",
  "item2": {
    "sub_item1": "foo",
    "sub_item2": "bar"
  }
}
'''

c = myClass.from_json(sampleData)
print(c.json)
```

*Disclaimer*: I am the creator and maintenor of this library.

Answer (score 2):

**orjson** is very fast, correct Python JSON library supporting dataclasses, datetimes, and numpy

https://github.com/ijl/orjson

Like so

[image]

Performance:

https://github.com/ijl/orjson#performance